# Detect Current Availability of GPS When Indoors in Swift

Tags: ios, gps, location-services

I want to find out if GPS is really available at a given instant in time. 
 I know it is possible to detect whether GPS is authorized and whether a phone has GPS enabled using something like:

i

```
f([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // show the map
} else {
    // show error
}
```

However, I can't find out how to detect if the GPS is really reachable a a given instant.  For example, if might be unavailable if the user is indoors or going through a tunnel.

Can anyone suggest a way to detect actual availablility of GPS data?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: All you can do is request location updates and check the `horizontalAccuracy` property. If it is 10m then you can be sure you are getting GPS signals.  Any other value and you may or may not.

Comment: Ok. Will do.  Thx.